# Defining Python List of Many values

Tags: arcgis-pro, list

I want to iterate through a layer that has about 500 records. In my code, I'm using a definition query inside a for loop to iterate through a test list:

```
listx = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

My question (probably an elementary one), is how to just call out all records instead of manually typing all 500 object ID's? I want to iterate through all Object IDs, while ingesting each ID into the definition query. I thought trying [:] or [*] or [0:500] would work, but they don't.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import mp

p  = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps("Map")[0]

lyr1 = m.listLayers("No_Other")[0]
lyr2 = m.listLayers("No_Admin")[0]

#obid = "OBJECTID in (409, 764, 114, 776)"
obid = "OBJECTID = {}"
listx = [114, 409, 764, 776]


for oid in listx:
    lyr2.definitionQuery = obid.format(oid)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr1, 'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE', lyr2, "150 Miles", 'ADD_TO_SELECTION', 'NOT_INVERT')
    lyr2.definitionQuert = None
    print(lyr2.definitionQuery)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
oids = ''
for x in listx:
    oids = oids + str(x) + ','
query = 'OBJECTID IN (' + oids[:-1] + ')'
```

Then give this query to your Selection call.  The reason for the [:-1] is that the final ',' needs to be removed for the SQL query to work.

If you simply want to select all features with your query, use "OBJECTID IS NOT NULL" and that will return everything.

Comment: Thanks, but what do I pass in for 'listx' if I'm replacing listx with the query line?

Comment: If you have a list (listx) of certain features, you can create a query from that to pass using this.  If you mean that you want to select all features, you don't need a query at all.  If that's the case, use a line like what @BERA has presented.  But per your original question, this would work.

Comment: Yes, looks like I'm trying to do more of what @BERA recommended. How do I compensate for the commas in the list defined by the 'oids' statement? Asking because, the definition query is failing and stopping at "OBJECTID = (1,)", so it's not proceeding to the next OBJECTID.

Comment: See the updated answer above

Comment: I think I'm still missing something in your answer. I understand the inclusion of [:-1], but the values returned look like: "(1,)". For some reason it's putting all ObjectID values inside parens.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure i understand your question but to list all objectids:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\database.gdb\feature_class' #Change to match your data. It can also be a feature layer with a definition query

oids = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, 'OID@')]
```